# How to print two variables in same line

Tags: java, eclipse

How to print string and integer value in same line. I can print in separate line

daljeet

16

I want to print like this daljeet 16

```
public class hello {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String name = "daljeet";

        int age = 16;


        System.out.println(" " +name +age);



    }

    }
```

Program output
 daljeet16

How to get space between two variables ?

Comment: `System.out.println(name + " " + age);`

Comment: As a side note, it’s always a good idea to start class names in Java with a capital letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class hello {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

  String name = "daljeet";

  int age = 16;

  System.out.println(name + " " + age);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The lazy way would be to just put a space at the back of the variable `name` i.e `"daljeet "`. Otherwise, you could write the following:

```
System.out.println(name + " " + age);
```